# Vector Based Mode

Tags: c++, vector

Mode being the number(s) that appear most frequently in a set of numbers 
I need my code to be able to handle single modes, multi-modes and no modes. 
I have the following code that i am currently using, but it has a few bugs:

```
vector<int> findMode(vector<int>& v){
int curBig = 0;
int absBig = 0;


vector<int> mode;
vector<int>::iterator it;
//sort for easy comparing of numbers
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
//loop for as long as the vector is
for (auto x : v){
    //as long as x is less than the size of v, do the rest (if x was the size of v, then v[x+1] would be out of bounds
    if (x < v.size() - 1){
        //compare the current number and the number after it
        if (v[x] == v[x + 1]){
            //if they're the same incrament current big by 1
            curBig++;
            //if current big is bigger than the absolute big then set absBig to curBig
            if (curBig > absBig){
                absBig = curBig;
            }
        }
        //reset curBig for the next set of numbers
        else
            curBig = 0;

    }//x < v.size()
}//auto x : v

int newBig = 0;
//if abs is not 0, do the following
if (absBig > 0){
    for (auto x : v){
        //runs basically the same ifs as above
        if (x < v.size() - 1){
            if (v[x] == v[x + 1]){
                newBig++;
                //this is supposed to push the mode(s) to the back of the vector
                if (newBig == absBig){
                    mode.push_back(v[v.front() + x]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
else if (absBig == 0)
    mode.push_back(-999);


return mode;
```

}

And then in the main, i used this to print out the mode(s):

```
if (mode[0] != -999){
    cout << "{";
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = mode.begin(); it != mode.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it;
        if (it < mode.end() - 1){
            cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << "}" << endl;
    }
}
else
    cout << "No Modes" << endl;
```

Theres just simply two bugs that i cant figure out. 
if the vector of ints has a mode of two (i.e: 1,2,2,3,4,etc. [the mode being 2]), the program sees that as simply "No mode". Obviously i am off by a factor of 1 somewhere, i just cant see where exactly.

And the second bug i am experiencing is that "mode.push_back(v[v.front() + x]);" isnt doing what it's supposed to. in my mind, any number that matches the criteria (any number that is a mode), should be pushed to the back of the mode vector, but for some reason, my mode vector can only store one number. Do i perhaps have a syntax error i can't see?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (auto x : v){
```

This iterates through all elements of `v`, not through all indices of `v`. So you cannot use this for-loop to test the position you are currently at or index `v`, like you do here:

```
if (v[x] == v[x + 1]){
```

Use a loop over indices instead:

```
for(unsigned x = 0; x < v.size(); ++x)
```

Since you are always stopping the loop already when `x < v.size()-1`, you can also use

```
for(unsigned x = 0; x < v.size()-1; ++x)
```

which will make the check unnecessary.

`push_back` inserts one given element to the end of the vector. So

```
 mode.push_back(v[v.front() + x]);
```

would insert one element of `v`. However it should be `v[x]`, not `v[v.front() + x]`. `v.front()` returns the value of the first element of `v`, to which you add `x` and then get the element of `v` at that position (which doesn't sound right to me). `v[v.front() + x]` is equivalent to `v[v[0] + x]`.

In the second loop you forgot to reset the counter once you find differing elements. This here:

```
//reset curBig for the next set of numbers
else
    curBig = 0;
```

should also appear there (but with `newBig` instead of `curBig`).

Also note that your code probably should return `v` if there is no element appearing twice, because technically all elements are modes in that case.

Comment: I will try what you said. I had v[x] beforehand, and decided it was correct, however someone (on here) told me otherwise (to use v.front() etc), so without questioning, i used his method, I will implement your suggestions, and get back with an answer in a few

Comment: @CristianC. In order for my last suggestion to work, you also need to replace the for-loops as I suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion fixed up one of my bugs, now just one to go, and i will be quite very happy.
for(unsigned x = 0; x < v.size(); ++x) fixed the whole (1, 1, 2,) not registering 1 as the mode

but it still only is able to push back one mode to the back of the vector
(ie. if the input is 1,1,2,2,3,3. it will say 1 is the mode
but that is not the case, 1, 2 and 3 should all be the mode.

Comment: @CristianC. Found solution for the second problem, see my answer

Comment: personally, i believe the bug is somewhere in:
for (unsigned x = 0; x < v.size(); ++x) {
   if (x < v.size() - 1){
    if (v[x] == v[x + 1]){
     newBig++;
     if (newBig == absBig){
      mode.push_back(v[x]);
     }
    }
   }

The only problem is that when i look at my code, the logic seems to be sound

Comment: you are a god amongst men. thank you so much. I have been looking at this code for days, with no avail. To me it was just a giant blob of code that should work. thank you for your help.

Comment: @CristianC. With some practise this is simple stuff, but if my answer helped you then consider accepting it.